# Animations doesn't work, using jquery, using animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to animate a img on html but it doesn't work

**html**:

```
<img class="col span-1-of-6 js--wp-1" src="img/emerson.jpg" alt="">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.js--wp-1').waypoint(function(direction) {
      $('.js--wp-1').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    }, {
      offset: '50%'
    });
  });
```

the console shows me these erros:
[image]

if you can't see the img:

```
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: f.getClientRects is not a function
    at r.fn.init.offset (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:4:20140)
    at t.(anonymous function) [as offset] (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js:7:8010)
    at e.refresh (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js:7:4744)
    at e.add (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js:7:2807)
    at new t (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js:7:827)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js:7:8466)
    at Function.each (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:2715)
    at r.fn.init.each (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:1003)
    at r.fn.init.waypoint (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js:7:8337)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/script.js:3:20)
offset @ jquery.min.js:4
t.(anonymous function) @ jquery.waypoints.min.js:7
e.refresh @ jquery.waypoints.min.js:7
e.add @ jquery.waypoints.min.js:7
t @ jquery.waypoints.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ jquery.waypoints.min.js:7
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.waypoints.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ script.js:3
j @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Everything is linked on the html, I don't understand what's going wrong. can anyone help me?

Comment: in the html have you included jquery.waypoints.min.js

Comment: add from cdn https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js

Comment: yes <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

Comment: using that cdn actually worked, must be some compatibility problem. thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img class="col span-1-of-6 js_wp_1" src="img/emerson.jpg" alt="">


$(".js_wp_1").waypoint(function() {
   $('.js_wp_1').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
  }
}, { offset: '50%'});
```

REplace the - with _ also